# how to get tablesorter to work if loading with getscript.

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am loading tablesorter using jquery .getscript.

```
WOI_.loadeddatatables = false;

$.getScript("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.22.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js").done(function(script, textStatus ){   
    console.log("text status " + textStatus);
    WOI_.loadeddatatables = true;

    }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception){

      console.log(jqxhr);

});
```

later on I have some code that checks if WOI_.loadeddatatables is true and calls sorttable if it is.

```
WOI_.functions.sorttable = function(el){
     console.log(el);

     el.tablesorter(); 
}

if(WOI_.loadeddatatables){
     WOI_.functions.sorttable($("#userwidgetstats"));
}
```

My text status is success, so the script has loaded, if I check it in the resources panel I can also see it has loaded.

console.log(el) gives me back a jquery element with a length of 1.

The table has a structure that seems to be what tablesorter is looking for - a thead and a tbody, thead with tr and multiple th elements, tbody with multiple tr. At any rate if there was some problem with the table structure I would expect it would raise some other error.

So really it seems like tablesorter just doesn't like to be loaded by getscript. Is that right?

Comment: Is jQuery loaded first? What is the `sortable` function? Also, add `debug: true` to tablesorter's initialization code to see if there are any issues.

Comment: thanks I will try the debug: true, there's no sortable there's WOI_.functions.sorttable which just calls tablesorter on the passed in element.

Comment: jquery is loaded first.

Comment: debug: true didn't do anything, I guess because tablesorter never gets added to jquery as a function passing in debug: true to it doesn't give me anything. :)  anyway decided I wasted too much time with this functionality and went with this solution instead: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/